# Using Hadoop streaming with unmolested binary data

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to make a script that pipes HDFS files through a Unix filter using a Hadoop streaming map-only job.  I don't care about input splits, my files are all compressed anyway.  I don't care about key/value pairs, and I'm having a heck of a time getting rid of the tabs hadoop wants to stick in my output.  I would prefer simple raw binary data in and out, but I could live with lines of UTF-8 text or similar.

I have tried various settings for `mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator` and `stream.map.output.field.separator`, using [typedbytes](http://static.last.fm/johan/huguk-20090414/klaas-hadoop-1722.pdf), etc.  The tabs just won't go away.  Any ideas?

I'm using CDH 4.1 with YARN (MRv2) if that makes a difference.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the `TextOuputFormat` if you don't want tabs/utf-8?

Comment: If there's a better output format I'd be happy to use it.  My immediate use case is text, but raw binary would be more general and (one presumes) faster.